# Safari browser truncating POST parameters

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, safari

My code works absolutely fine on other browsers than Safari 6.1.2 on Mac OS Lion.

Below is the ajax post that I use -

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'text/html',
     url:"/MyProxy.php",
     data:{"server":"mydomain.com", "user":"vijay", "passd":"highly@secret"},
     error: function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         alert("Failure - "+data);
         return;
     },
     success: function(data) {
         console.log("Success - "+data);
         parseInformation(data);
     }
 });
```

Also for debug purpose, I have entered logs on my PHP server code

```
header('cache-control: no-cache');

function getRealPOST() {
    $pairs = explode("&", file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $vars = array();
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $nv = explode("=", $pair);
        $name = urldecode($nv[0]);
        $value = urldecode($nv[1]);
        $vars[$name] = $value;
    }                   
    return $vars;
} 

echo "-------";         
var_dump($_POST);           
echo "-------";             

print_r(getRealPOST());
```

In Safari on console logs it shows something like -

```
-------array(2) {
  ["userName"]=>
  string(5) "vijay"
  ["passwd"]=>
  string(4) "hig"
}
-------Array
(
    [

serverAdd] => mydomain.com
    [userName] => vijay
    [passwd] => hig
)
```

Any guess why only Safari is behaving in such way, even with iPad/iPhone and other OS where Safari is used as browser, I am facing this truncation problem. I have also read post where people are facing such issues, however, in those cases, they were having very large request, mine on other hand is just small request.

Any help?

Comment: Could you give the result of your PHP code with the POST parameters? Did you find a solution? or where the issue came from? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to find the solution. The PHP code is as posted above with minimal functionality.

Comment: Are those the exact values you tested with this functionality or only an example. Meaning could the correct value have special characters in the password that result in truncation.

Comment: try changing the name of the key from "server" to something else, like "my_domain"

Comment: Try removing unnecessary quotation marks when creating json object:

data:{server:"mydomain.com", user:"vijay", passd:"highly@secret"}

also try to change dataType to just "html"

Comment: Thank you for the help @RafałMnich however, I have closed that work for now, so I would not be able to verify this any time sooner now.

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code and I had an issue with the `dataType: 'text/html'` parameter of your request. Usually there is no need to specify it, jQuery is smart enough to understand the format the received outcome.

Removing the `dataType` parameter anyway I received the desired output:

[image: this is the screenshot of Safari console]

I would also suggest you to use a proxy like Charles https://www.charlesproxy.com to view the real output obtained by the PHP script so you can figure out if you have a problem on javascript or server side.